# Adding second class to gridview row in RowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I wish to add an additional class to a GridView programatically.  I know I can do this using the following code:

```
public void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
    if (!row.Field<Boolean>("IsActive"))
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["class"] += "InActive";
    }
}
```

and it works fine.  The class "IsActive" is added, however, on alternating rows I end up with this HTML:

```
<tr class="gvAlternatingStyle" class="InActive"
    onmouseover="gvMouseOver(this)" 
    onmouseout="gvMouseOut(this)" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

Two class definitions is not what I want. I would prefer to have something like this:

```
<tr class="gvAlternatingStyle InActive"
    onmouseover="gvMouseOver(this)" 
    onmouseout="gvMouseOut(this)" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

which is, of course, more valid.

I cannot seem to figure out where/how to adjust this html.  Possibly in OnPreRender() but I don't see where.   Can anyone give me a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After muddling with this a while and with help from VDWWD I worked out how to accomplish this with a combination of the above and OnPreRender():

```
    public void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
            DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
            if (!row.Field<Boolean>("IsActive"))               {
                e.Row.Attributes["class"] += "InActive";                
    }


    protected void PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.Attributes["class"] == "InActive")&& 
                (row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)){
                row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Normal;
                row.Attributes["class"] = "gvAlternatingStyle InActive";

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take care of the `AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass` yourself and add the extra class when needed. You will need to remove it from the GridView header of course.

```
string AlternatingRowStyleCssClass;

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string myClass = string.Empty;

        //get the AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass for reference into a variable and delete from the gridview itself
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            AlternatingRowStyleCssClass = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass;
            GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "";
        }

        //check if the row is alternate, if so set the alternating class
        if (e.Row.RowIndex % 2 == 1)
        {
            myClass = AlternatingRowStyleCssClass;
        }

        //check if you need to add the extra class
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        if (!row.Field<Boolean>("IsActive"))
        {
            myClass += " Inactive";
        }

        //add all the classes to the row
        e.Row.Attributes["class"] = myClass.Trim();
    }

    //add the class to the gridview again (maybe relevant for postback)
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = AlternatingRowStyleCssClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually just implemented something similar (occurred to me as I typed this question) but I was still interested to see if there was a way to do it without programming the alternating style by hand :).    Thanks for the quick response!!   I'll mark yours as the answer if nobody comes up with a direct solution to the above.

Comment: I think the class defined in `AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass` is added later then what happens in the `OnRowDataBound` event. I did a quick test with `e.Row.Attributes.Remove("class");` and then adding the new class again, but that did not work, the class was still added.

Comment: Yea, I agree.  Still experimenting.  I looked at it in the OnPreRender but the classes aren't there yet either.

Comment: I want to add that the big drawback of using your solution (above) is that I have my app highly skinned.  This sorta breaks the skin of that grid and adds additional headaches.

Comment: I found a quick fix where you can still define the class in the gridview header itself. Then it is stored in a variable and removed from the grid so it is not used later on and breaks the class added in the rowdatabound event.

Comment: I actually worked out a method to do this in OnPreRender (sorta tricky) but I'd like to see what you mean here.   Can you adjust your answer?

Comment: That's interesting.  I haven't tried to implement it yet.   I am surprised it works given that the AlternatingRowStyle is applied after prerender.  Pretty slick.    I am going to go with the one I found which, to me, seems a little more elegant but I would like any comments you can provide.  You did help point me to this solution.  I'll post it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136371/discussion-between-jon-glazer-and-vdwwd).