# Gridview dropping milliseconds from database timestamp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, rowdatabound

I have a `Gridview` that displays record from a database, including a timestamp.

In the `RowDataBound` event, I'm trying to check the timestamp to see if I need to disable a button but the milliseconds are dropped and so my comparisons aren't working correctly.

**How do I preserve the milliseconds from the database all the way to the `RowDataBound` event?**

My code:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable

Using cn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyConStr"))
    cn.Open()

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("spGetRecords", cn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstParm", FirstParm)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondParm", SecondParm)

    Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dt.Load(reader)
    End Using
End Using

gvMyGrid.DataSource = dt
gvMyGrid.DataBind()
```

And my `RowDataBound`:

```
Protected Sub gvMyGrid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvMyGrid.RowDataBound
    If gvNotes.DataSource.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim someTime As DateTime = "03/18/2019 08:28:09.090"
        If e.Row.Cells.Item(timestampIndex).Text = someTime 'This is never true because the cell text drops the milliseconds
            'Disable button here...
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont see anything resembling a timestamp used in `gvMyGrid_RowDataBound`?

Comment: @VDWWD - I edited the code for clarity on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @VDWWD - In my example above, I'm expecting `e.Row.Cells.Item(timestampIndex).Text` to eventually be equal to `someTime`. But on the row that is supposed to evaluate to true, `e.Row.Cells.Item(timestampIndex).Text` is equal to `03/18/2019 08:28:09` instead of `03/18/2019 08:28:09.090`.

Comment: Cell text is not a timestamp. You need to use the correct data object bound to the GridView. See examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220948/gridview-rowdatabound-not-working-on-first-row and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393601/adding-second-class-to-gridview-row-in-rowdatabound/42394794